# Django 1.8 app templates not being detected

Tags: django, django-templates

Changed template files for app are not being loaded, here are my settings:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            # os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                # Insert your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS here or use this
                # list if you haven't customized them:
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.template.context_processors.static',
                'django.template.context_processors.tz',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.core.context_processors.request',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

And screen of templates structure(Url is model name):

[image]

What am I missing ? (keywords app is indeed in installed_apps)

Edit: Tried uncommenting #dirs but it still doesnt work.

**Is it possible that this messes things up(on top of settings):**

```
 BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

if I delete this line it gives 502error.(nginx)

**edit 2:**

If I change BASE_DIR to: BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(**file**))

then it starts reading templates but from PROJECT not app templates file (django_project/django_project/templates/admin) is it possible to change this so it reads from app directory instead?

Comment: You've commented out the line that actually sets the dirs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You have to understand how to configure your templates engines :

> Here’s a simple setup that tells the Django template engine to load
>   templates from the templates subdirectory inside each installed
>   application (**APP_DIRS** : True) :

```py
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'DIRS': []
    },
]
```

The **DIRS** list allow you to add some other folders where Django will search templates

Django recommend to organize your templates like this for each apps : **django_project/app/templates/app/**
In your case : **django_project/keyword/templates/keyword/**

Here is your final architecture :

```bash
django_project
├── keyword
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── static
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── keyword
│   │       ├── admin
│   │       │   ├── Url
│   │       │   │   ├── base_site.html
│   │       │   │   └── change_list.html
│   │       │   └── base_site.html
│   │       ├── base.html
│   │       ├── embeds.html
│   │       └── index.html
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   └── views.py
├── django_project 
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
└── manage.py
```

Since the template engine search in each **app/templates/**, in the view of your app, you define a relative path to your template.

E.g :

```
render(request, 'keyword/admin/base_site.html', context)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this.  The key to the solution was your last line.  Everywhere you refer to hardcoded values like render()  (also "extends" and "static" usage) you need to prepend <app> to your links.  I thought Django was smart and doing this for us, didn't realize I had to fix those too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates/admin'),
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates/Url'),
        ],
```

That way, Django knows to look into sub-directories of the `templates` folder as well.